# Nginx: Leverage browser caching for remote resources (images)

Tags: nginx, cache, image, cache-control

There are some images in one site of mine which are hosted to a remote server.
I haven't figured out yet how to set `Cache-Control` to remote sources.
For local files I'm using:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpe?g|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|css|js|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?ver=[0-9.]+)?$ {
    expires 1M;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
    }
```

Which is working great.

I tried to add a location block containing the remote location of the files following the same principle with the local file, say for example https://example.com/img/ but nginx didnt do anything.
The purpose of all this is to increase site speed.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the headers for remote resources by changing anything on your server. You need to change them on the server that's serving the files.

The only way I can think to achieve this would be to proxy the images through a dedicated path on your server, but that would require changing the HTML to point to that path.

Comment: in other words, to save the remote images to my server, then change the image path to my html. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.